# Cannot establish connection to sql-server using pyodbc on Windows 10

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure, pyodbc

Getting this error when trying to run development server on django.

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Here is my settings.py databases

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'mydata',
    'USER': 'user@mydata',
    'PASSWORD': '**password**',
    'HOST': 'mydata.database.windows.net',
    'PORT':'**port**',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'SQL Server',
        'host_is_server': True,
        'MultipleActiveResultSets': False,
        'Encrypt': True,
        'TrustServerCertificate': False,
        'Connection Timeout': 30,
        'Persist Security Info': False,
    },
},
}
```

I have `django-pyodbc` and `django-pyodbc-azure` installed.

Using django version 1.11.

Any help would be awesome! Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

I changed driver to SQL Sever and updated the driver. Now I am getting this error.

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have the database set up on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error information, there are two possible reason which caused the issue, as below.

1. The `driver` option value should be `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server` as the figure below from Azure portal. Please change it and try again.

[image]

2. The `access denied` error may be caused by not adding your client IP to the firewall of Azure SQL Database to allow access, as the figure below.

[image]

Hope it helps.